# Как разлогинить всех пользователей сайта?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity-2

Требуется разлогинивать всех пользователей в определенное время каждый день. Для аутентификации используется .AspNetCore.Identity. Можно ли вызвать .SignOutAsync() для всех пользователей? Если нет, то как вызвать этот метод для каждого залогиненого пользователя? Проблема заключается в том, что некоторые из пользователей не умеют обновлять страницу, как бы странно это не звучало. Может быть есть другой путь обновлять их страницы принудительно? Также возникает вопрос, можно ли использовать для этого Quartz, ведь он работает в одном экземпляре для сервера, не создавая экземпляр для каждой отдельной сессии.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // укзывает, будет ли валидироваться издатель при валидации токена
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    // строка, представляющая издателя
                    ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.Issuer,

                    // будет ли валидироваться потребитель токена
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    // установка потребителя токена
                    ValidAudience = AuthOptions.Audience,
                    // будет ли валидироваться время существования
                    ValidateLifetime = true,

                    // установка ключа безопасности
                    IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                    // валидация ключа безопасности
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            //экспериментировал с этим параметром, но он добавляет
            //время к авторизации, а нужно сбрасывать всем , в одно 
            // и тоже время.
            // можно было бы вычислить тут время суток
            // но возникает вопрос:
            // будет ли оно вычисляться отдельно для каждой
            // аутентификации или DateTime.Now будет константой
            // вычисленной при старте приложения
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 15, 25, 00) - DateTime.Now; 
        });
```

Comment: У вас JWT, как я понимаю, когда генерируете JWT, то там можно указать время жизни токена, покажите код генерации токена.

Answer (score 0):

> Требуется разлогинивать всех пользователей в определенное время каждый день

В настройках авторизации выдавайте время действия кук (Если у вас авторизация на куках) на период

```
var expiretionTime = new DateTime("Дату, когда нужно разлогинить") - DateTime.Now;
```

А потом просто в конфигурации авторизации закиньте это значение в время жизни вашей куки

Comment: Вы не подскажите, как это сделать? код  с комментариями добавил к вопросу

Comment: @Vasiliy, технически, вы сделали правильно, а что у вас не так получается?

Comment: @Vasiliy, стоит так же отметить, что авторизация на локалхосте и на хостинге работает по разному, т.е.. даже если у вас стоит время авторизации на неделю, вас может запрашивать авторизацию каждых пол часа или 5 минут

Comment: @Vasiliy, судя по вашему коду, теперь каждому юзеру просто будет выдаваться токен авторизации ДО 15:25, после чего авторизация будет сбрасываться. По идеи, данный код должен работать так, как задумано.

Comment: Faraday, не работает так, к сожалению. При попытке авторизоваться после указанного времени не пускает. При попытке авторизоваться раньше, не разлогинивает. Думаю, это связано с тем, что данное значение времени вычисляется один раз при старте приложения (

Comment: Пробовал как локально, так и на хосте, результат одинаковый

Comment: @Vasiliy, это плохо, но, я помог чем мог